# "ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" sometimes in time execution

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

i am  using crashlityc and  was looking for this error  for several hours. it works, but with some users i have this error:

> android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource
>   (ArrayAdapter.java:394) android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView
>   (ArrayAdapter.java:362) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure (AbsSpinner.java:197)
>   android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure (Spinner.java:541)
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure (AppCompatSpinner.java:418)
>   android.view.View.measure (View.java:17951)
>   (ZygoteInit.java:1200)

In my class i have this:

```
private void setPhoneNumbers() {
 ... code .......
  ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_text, numbers);
  spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  mPhoneNumbersSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}`
```

In my .xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:textColor="@color/menu_header_txt"
      android:textSize="13sp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@android:id/text1" />`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need to use the following `ArrayAdapter` constructor mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[])):

```
ArrayAdapter (Context context, 
                int resource, 
                int textViewResourceId, 
                T[] objects)
```

In your case:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_text, R.id.text1, numbers);
```

Comment: i had tried this before but i have this error "Error:(301, 118) error: cannot find symbol variable text1" but it is in the TextView, thanks anyway

Comment: @Toncs  Oh...my bad, change `android:id="@android:id/text1"` to `android:id="@+id/text1"`